# Calling a SQL server procedure from a function in VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2, ms-access-2010

I am trying to call a SQL Server procedure to validate user from a function in VBA.

Please see the code below:

proc_validate_user accepts userId and password as input parameters and returns a bit value of 0 or 1

function to call this proc is as under:

```vbs
Public Function ExecUDF(userId As Integer, pwd As String)

    Dim cmd As DAO.Command
    Dim par As DAO.Parameter
    Dim ret As Variant

    Set cmd = New DAO.Command
    cmd.ActiveConnection = CurrentDb.Connection
    cmd.CommandText = "proc_validate_user"
    cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc

    'Define the input and output variables and append them to the collection
    Set par = cmd.CreateParameter("@userID")
    cmd.Parameters.Append par
    Set par = cmd.CreateParameter("@pwd")
    cmd.Parameters.Append par
    Set par = cmd.CreateParameter("@isValid", adParamOutput)
    cmd.Parameters.Append par

    cmd.Parameters("@userID") = userId
    cmd.Parameters("@pwd") = pwd
    cmd.Execute

'and then assign the stored procedure return value to the access variable

    ret = cmd.Parameters("@isValid").Value



End Function
```

I am getting an compilation error saying User defined type not defined  at "Dim cmd As DAO.Command"

Comment: What is `DAO`? || you have a typo and aren't closing your function.

Comment: DAO stands data access object and is a subset of ADO. It is used very commonly and I have used it in other part of my code where it works beautifully. For ex: DAO.Recordset

Comment: Yes... But is it included / in scope? The error message seems to suggest that the compiler doesn't know what `DAO.Command` is.

Comment: DAO.Recordset works fine and when I was checking help in how to call a sql server procedure from VB, I came to know about these commands ADODB.command and CreateParameter functions etc. I tried to write the code with ADODB as well as DAO and both give me the same error.

Comment: both give the same error of the type `DAO.Command` not being defined?

Comment: Error doesn't say DAO.Command not defined. It says "Compile error: User-defined type not defined" at the same line. doesn't matter if it is DAO or ADODB.

Comment: Does that line reference any other types? No. Your problem is that Visual Studio or whatever compiler you're using doesn't recognise the type you're trying to use. The most likely cause is that you're lacking a reference to the necessary assemblies or an `Import` statement somewhere in your program.

Comment: When I press DAO. followed by ctrl+[space], I get  a drop down but it doesn't contain the command DAO.Command. When i key in ADODB. followed by ctrl+[space], i get nothing. I think the problem is that I need to find equivalent  of ADODB.Command in DAO. which I am unable to do so obviously. :(

Comment: Got passed the error, Added the reference to use ADODB object from tools->reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing up the DAO and ADO object models. DAO is a completely different model, not a "subset of ADO". There is no `DAO.Command` object.

SQL Server stored procedures that produce output parameters can be a nuisance to work with using DAO. The ADO model is much better aligned with SQL Server, so I would suggest using code like this:

```vbs
Public Function ExecUDF(userId As Integer, pwd As String) As Boolean
    Dim con As ADODB.Connection, cmd As ADODB.Command, connStr As String, isValid As Boolean
    ' remove "ODBC;" prefix from the .Connect property of an existing ODBC linked table
    connStr = Mid(CurrentDb.TableDefs("dbo_my_table").Connect, 6)
    Set con = New ADODB.Connection
    con.Open connStr
    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
    cmd.ActiveConnection = con
    cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    cmd.CommandText = "proc_validate_user"
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@userID", adInteger, adParamInput, , userId)
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@pwd", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 50, pwd)
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@isValid", adBoolean, adParamOutput)
    cmd.Execute
    isValid = cmd.Parameters("@isValid").Value
    Set cmd = Nothing
    con.Close
    Set con = Nothing
    ExecUDF = isValid  ' return the value
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you  Gord, I figured this out already as I mentioned. I am however stuck with using the function that i just created in my cmd_Login_Click() routine. I am assigning it to value :                                                       PasswordValid = ExecUDF(userId, pwd) and it throws me an error saying "3251 operation is not supported for this type of object". I truly appreciate your help.

Comment: If it is just a matter of getting the value back from the VBA function then have a look at my updated code.

Comment: Hi Gord, I get "procedure or function has too many arguments"  after I modified the code based on your suggestion. my DB proc looks like this  `CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.proc_validate_user
(@userID int, @hashPassword varchar(MAX), @isValid bit output)
AS
DECLARE @ret bit
  if EXISTS(select * from TBL_User_Login where userID = @userID and password = @hashPassword)
    SET @ret = 1
  else
    SET @ret = 0
SELECT @isValid =@ret
GO`

Comment: By the way, I already changed the code `cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@pwd", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 50, pwd)` to `cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@hashPassword", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 50, pwd)`

Comment: Got it resolved by changing the proc defintion in SQL Server. thank you Gord